# How do update Python on Azure Linux VM

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine

I'm trying to install Python 3.6.1 on an Azure Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but its stuck at Python 3.5.2.

Commands I have tried:

```
sudo apt --upgrade
sudo apt --upgrade python3
sudo apt --update
sudo apt remove python3
sudo apt install python 3.6.1 (doing sudo apt install python3.7 doesn't work)
```

I've never had to deal with this on a local Linux install.

Comment: Most of those commands are wrong. `upgrade` and `update` don't have leading dashes, and `apt install python 3.6.1` tries to install _two_ things: `python` and something called `3.6.1`. In any case, [Ubuntu 16.04 ships Python 3.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3). If you want a newer version you won't get it through official packages. Compile it from source, use something like `pyenv`, `pythonz`, or `conda`, use a PPA, upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu,... Some of those might be better depending on your specific use case.

Comment: I typed the commands without the dashes, I was just so irritated I forgot to remove them. But thanks on the suggestion, I will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To install the Python version Python 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 16.04. You can build python from source.  Alternatively, you can install it from PPA.

**To build python from source**

First, Install some build dependencies using the commands below.

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall

sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Then, download Python 3.6.1 source code from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/).

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.1/Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
```

Next, extract the tarball.

```
tar xvf Python-3.6.1.tar.xz
```

Now cd into the source directory, configure the build environment and install.

```
cd Python-3.6.1/

./configure

sudo make altinstall
```

**To install it from PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6

sudo apt update

sudo apt install python3.6
```

You could get more information from

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-python-3-6-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-17-04

and  [how to install the latest Python 3.6.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS via PPA](https://gist.github.com/tiagocardosos/501b11e156621aa9e62909d4bfa9741a).